# Does QGIS automatically convert lat/lon and UTM coordinates?

Tags: qgis

I have two coordinates of the same location.
Lat/lon, UTM coordinates.

I made the coordinates of EPSG:32634 UTM zone 34N into a csv file and sent it to QGIS.

And I loaded the Lat/lon coordinates (EPSG:4326) into csv -> QGIS, and the UTM coordinates and the lat/lon coordinates match.
I understand that they match because they are coordinates of the same location.

My QGIS coordinate system is EPSG:32634, but it was interesting to see that it matched when I put the coordinates of the 4326 coordinate system.

Does QGIS convert lat/lon coordinates to UTM coordinate system?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html?highlight=fly#on-the-fly-projection

Comment: for display in the map canvas, yes. But it does not change the shapefile's projection.